# Which time job picks picks up the new custom fields

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-field-types

I have created a Custom Field type and deployed it. I have noticed it takes some time the New field to appear on the new column form, somewhere from 30 mins to an hour. I could see the deployed xml file on this location:
*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML*

Could someone please suggest which timer job picks the new templates, such that i could test my changes quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are no jobs, It is just my slow server.